# Transpose a table row by row

Tags: google-sheets, transpose, flat

I need to transpose parts of a table row by row. The following example illustrates what the result needs to look like:

[image]

I tried different combinations of `arrayformula()`, `flatten()` and `transpose()`, succeeded with getting the last column right with `=arrayformula(FLATTEN(B4:C))`, but need now help with fixing this.

[Link to table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u4A-chaVWMJeam0_XnWEsoFuHFC51QY8OmT8h61n3uo/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in row 2 of the example screenshot:

`={flatten({A2:A,A2:A}),arrayformula(flatten({if(A2:A<>"",B$1,),if(A2:A<>"",C$1,)})),flatten({B2:C})}`

[image]

Or if you want the column headings, put this in row 1:

`={"A","B","C";flatten({A2:A,A2:A}),arrayformula(flatten({if(A2:A<>"",B$1,),if(A2:A<>"",C$1,)})),flatten({B2:C})}`

The new column 'C' ends up being a mixed data type, so be careful if you run a future `query` on these results as it doesn't like mixed data.

**For local implementation** (as per your initial screengrab, EU locale file), try this in cell `E4` - since the formula sits in row 4, the array range needs to go from 4 (`A4:A`):

`={flatten({A4:A\A4:A})\arrayformula(flatten({if(A4:A<>"";B$3;)\if(A4:A<>"";C$3;)}))\flatten({B4:C})}`

**Alternatively**, if you want column headings, try this in cell `E3` - the array range is still `A4:A` because `"A"\"B"\"C";` puts headings in row 3, `;` is a return, then the rest of the formula targets data from row 4 down:

`={"A"\"B"\"C";flatten({A4:A\A4:A})\arrayformula(flatten({if(A4:A<>"";B$3;)\if(A4:A<>"";C$3;)}))\flatten({B4:C})}`

If you want to limit the array range to a specific row rather than working down the entire sheet (eg. row 20), then `A4:A` would need to be `A4:A20`.

Comment: To get it working I had to edit your formula because of two issues to `={flatten({A2:A4;A2:A4})\arrayformula(flatten({if(A2:A4<>"";B$1;)\if(A2:A4<>"";C$1;)}))\flatten({B2:C4})}`: 1. The punctuation is different in the EU version - `,` needs to be a backslash in array to separate the array items and semicolon within formulas. 2. I get a `#REF!` (result could not be extended, add 3 more rows )when I use eg. `A2:A` instead `A2:A4. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: I've updated the answer for implementation based on your initial screenshot, on an EU location file.

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic SPLIT(FLATTEN( problem.

Arrayformula() can always exist on the outside of a formula and will apply to the whole thing.
This is on a new tab in your sample called MK.Help:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TO_TEXT(SPLIT(FLATTEN(Data!A2:A&"|"&Data!B1:C1&"|"&Data!B2:C);"|";0;0));"where Col1<>''"))
```